# Ler array multidimensional JSON via PHP

Tags: php, json, api, array-multidimensional

Senhores, estou tendo dificuldade na leitura de um JSON que vem via API, recebo ele da seguinte maneira:

```
$json_file = file_get_contents("https://allsportsapi.com/api/football/?met=H2H&APIkey=MINHA_KEY");
$json_decode = json_decode($json_file, true);
echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($json_decode);
```

Através de um print_r tenho o seguinte retorno:

```
Array(
[success] => 1
[result] => Array
    (
        [H2H] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [event_key] => 273338
                        [event_date] => 2020-01-21
                        [event_time] => 21:15
                        [event_home_team] => Chelsea
                        [home_team_key] => 2616
                        [event_away_team] => Arsenal
                        [away_team_key] => 2617
                        [event_halftime_result] => 1 - 0
                        [event_final_result] => 2 - 2
                        [event_status] => Finished
                        [country_name] => England
                        [league_name] => Premier League
                        [league_key] => 148
                        [league_round] => Round 24
                        [league_season] => 
                        [event_live] => 0
                        [event_country_key] => 41
                    ) )
[firstTeamResults] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [event_key] => 273383
                        [event_date] => 2020-03-08
                        [event_time] => 15:00
                        [event_home_team] => Chelsea
                        [home_team_key] => 2616
                        [event_away_team] => Everton
                        [away_team_key] => 2612
                        [event_halftime_result] => 2 - 0
                        [event_final_result] => 4 - 0
                        [event_status] => Finished
                        [country_name] => England
                        [league_name] => Premier League
                        [league_key] => 148
                        [league_round] => Round 29
                        [league_season] => 
                        [event_live] => 0
                        [event_country_key] => 41
                    ) ) 
[secondTeamResults] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [event_key] => 273381
                        [event_date] => 2020-03-07
                        [event_time] => 16:00
                        [event_home_team] => Arsenal
                        [home_team_key] => 2617
                        [event_away_team] => West Ham
                        [away_team_key] => 2620
                        [event_halftime_result] => 0 - 0
                        [event_final_result] => 1 - 0
                        [event_status] => Finished
                        [country_name] => England
                        [league_name] => Premier League
                        [league_key] => 148
                        [league_round] => Round 29
                        [league_season] => 
                        [event_live] => 0
                        [event_country_key] => 41
                    ) ) )
```

Onde para fazer a leitura utilizo um foreach:

```
if(count($json_decode)){
$i = 0;
foreach ($json_decode as $value) {
    echo $value["event_home_team"] . ", " . $value["league_name"] . "<br>";
  } } else {
echo "nenhum jogo no momento"; }
```

Onde estou errando no retorno dos valores?

Me retorna a seguinte mensagem: Trying to get property of non-object

Obrigado

Comment: Não precisa colocar "Resolvido" no título. Sei que é prática comum em muitos fóruns, mas aqui é diferente. Vc já [aceitou a resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) abaixo (clicou no ✔) e isso é o suficiente para indicar que o problema foi resolvido. Se vc quiser colocar sua própria solução, use o campo de resposta abaixo (veja o campo de texto "Sua resposta" na parte de baixo da página).

Comment: Ah sim, obrigado

Answer (score -1, accepted):

cara, você estava tentando acessar um array multidimensional e associativo como se ele fosse apenas $array[0]['event-home-team']. Existem outras formas de resolver o seu problema, mas a mais fácil e que talvez consuma menos recursos que encontrei foi essa:

```
<?php


 $arrays = Array(
'success' => 1,
'result' => Array
    (
        'H2H' => Array
            (
                Array
                    (
                        'event_key' => 273338,
                        'event_date' => '2020-01-21',
                        'event_time' => '21:15',
                        'event_home_team' => 'Chelsea',
                        'home_team_key' => 2616,
                        'event_away_team' => 'Arsenal',
                        'away_team_key' => 2617,
                        'event_halftime_result' => '1 - 0',
                        'event_final_result' => '2 - 2',
                        'event_status' => 'Finished',
                        'country_name' => 'England',
                        'league_name' => 'Premier League',
                        'league_key' => 148,
                        'league_round' => 'Round 24',
                        'league_season' => '',
                        'event_live' => 0,
                        'event_country_key' => '41',
                    ) ),
'firstTeamResults' => Array
            (
                '0' => Array
                    (
                        'event_key' => 273383,
                        'event_date' => '2020-03-08',
                        'event_time' => '15:00',
                        'event_home_team' => 'Chelsea',
                        'home_team_key' => 2616,
                        'event_away_team' => 'Everton',
                        'away_team_key' => 2612,
                        'event_halftime_result' => '2 - 0',
                        'event_final_result' => '4 - 0',
                        'event_status' => 'Finished',
                        'country_name' => 'England',
                        'league_name' => 'Premier League',
                        'league_key' => 148,
                        'league_round' => 'Round 29',
                        'league_season' => '',
                        'event_live' => 0,
                        'event_country_key' => 41,
                    ) ), 
'secondTeamResults' => Array
            (
                '0' => Array
                    (
                        'event_key' => 273381,
                        'event_date' => '2020-03-07',
                        'event_time' => '16:00',
                        'event_home_team' => 'Arsenal',
                        'home_team_key' => 2617,
                        'event_away_team' => 'West Ham',
                        'away_team_key' => 2620,
                        'event_halftime_result' => '0 - 0',
                        'event_final_result' => '1 - 0',
                        'event_status' => 'Finished',
                        'country_name' => 'England',
                        'league_name' => 'Premier League',
                        'league_key' => 148,
                        'league_round' => 'Round 29',
                        'league_season' => '',
                        'event_live' => 0,
                        'event_country_key' => 41,
                    ) )
   ));
    $keys = array_keys($arrays['result']);

for($i = 0; $i < count($keys);$i++){

echo $arrays['result'][$keys[$i]][0]['event_home_team'] . ", " . $arrays['result'][$keys[$i]][0]['league_name'] . "<br>";
    $i++;
```

}

note que eu representei seu array assim $arrays['result'][$keys[$i]][0]['event_home_team'], inseri um [0] caso ele possua outros itens dentro desse array terá que inserir uma variável no lugar e talvéz um if que acrescente ++ nessa varíavel.

Comment: Isso mesmo @MarcosVinicius, deu certo era ai o meu erro! Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Uma forma de percorrer todo o array é:

```
foreach($json_decode['result'] as $x=>$x_value){
     foreach ($x_value as $y=> $y_value){
    if($y_value['league_name']=! ''){     

        echo $y_value['event_home_team'] . ' x ' ;
        echo $y_value['event_away_team'] . ' - Data do Confronto ' . $y_value['event_date'] . ' - Horário ' . $y_value['event_time'];
        echo '<br>';                   
     }
}
}
```